# How to reference code from main entry point in secondary entry points so that secondary entry points use to the same symbols from main entry point

Tags: angular, typescript, bazel, ng-packagr

`ng-packagr` enables secondary entry points. At first glance, if secondary entry points are "standalone", it is easy.

However, I want to achieve a similar effect to what Angular is doing, e.g. in `HttpClientTestingModule`:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/testing/src/module.ts.

Namely: I want to have a secondary entry point like `@my-lib/testing` that exposed stuff for testing. But this stuff is dependant on `@my-lib` (just like `common/http/testing` depends on `import {HttpBackend, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';`).

When I simply import stuff from

`projects/my-lib/src`

into secondary entry point, the typescript compiler creates a completely new bundle, with copy of source code from `projects/my-lib/src`, but what is more, it creates different hidden exported symbols that are used internally (e.g. `i0` etc.) for dependency injection. As a result, if I do this in my testing secondary entry point:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MyLibModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyLibService,
      useClass: MyLibTestingService
    }
  ]
})
export class MyLibTestingModule { }
```

then `MyLibService` and `MyLibModule` are completely different things for Angular DI, and importing `MyLibTestingModule` in the application that consumes the library, does not have the desired effect (i.e. overriding the provider).

Looking at

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/testing/src/module.ts,

the angular team is using Bazel and in testing secondary entry point they refer to dependencies via package name

`import {HttpBackend, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';`

and it is Bazel that does the magic via this config:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/testing/BUILD.bazel

Is it possible to achieve the same result with Angular CLI's generated library that is using `ng-packagr` under the hood?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?